# Notifications API - Customization options?

Tags: html, google-chrome, notifications, web-notifications

I'm interested in using the html5 notifications api but have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to customize the notification background? By default it's white but I'd like to use black with a little transparency.
2. Is it possible to make the notification clickable? Or at least click back to the app in the Chrome browser? Or are notifications purposely not clickable?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, [Web Notifications](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebNotifications/publish/) is *not* part of HTML5.  Chrome is the only browser to implement it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of notifications:

1. `webkitNotifications.createNotification` - this will create a generic notification that can be passed exactly three items: Title, Icon, Content
2. `webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification` - this can be passed a url to an html page that will be displayed a notification

If you want more control than createNotification offers, use createHTMLNotification and pass it a custom html page.